# Left merging does not work

Tags: python, pandas

When I merge two simple dataframes, then everything works fine. But when I apply the same code to my real dataframes, then the merging does not work correctly:

I want to merge `df1` and `df2` on column `A` using left joining.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3','A4','A5'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3','C4','C5'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3','D4','A5']})

result = pd.merge(df1, df2[["A","C"]], how='left', on='A')
```

In this case the result is correct (the number of rows in `result` is the same as `df1`).

However when I run the same code on my real data, the number of rows in `result` is much larger than `df1` and is more similar to `df2`.

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2[["ID","EVENT"]], how='left', on='ID')
```

The field `ID` is of type String (`astype(str)`).

What might be the reason on this? I cannot post here the real dataset, but maybe some indications still might be done based on my explanation. Thanks.

**UDPATE:**

I checked the dataframe `result` and I can see many duplicated rows having the same `ID`. Why?

Comment: Maybe you have dup ID in df1 or df2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this slightly modified example (I modified the last two values in column `A` in `df2`):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3','A0','A0'],
                    'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3','C4','C5'],
                    'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3','D4','A5']})

result = pd.merge(df1, df2[["A","C"]], how='left', on='A')
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0  A0  B0  C0
1  A0  B0  C4
2  A0  B0  C5
3  A1  B1  C1
4  A2  B2  C2
5  A3  B3  C3
```

There is one `A0` row for each `A0` in `df2`. This is also what is happening with your data.

Comment: Thank you. This was the reason of the problem.